# Git ssh could not resolve hostname

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

If I want to clone a Git repository via SSH, I get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I need to use a proxy to connect to the internet. (proxy:8080)

In Git I can easily set the HTTP and HTTPS proxy via:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy:8080/
git config --global https.proxy http://proxy:8080/
```

How can this be achieved for SSH?

Comment: I had the same issue. Rebooting my computer fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSH doesn't work with an HTTP/HTTPS proxy. If your proxy supports SOCKS, you may be able to use git via SOCKS using a wrapper like tsocks or socksify or a redirection tool like redsocks. Those are options for Linux; on Windows maybe something like Widecap will help. Here's a more comprehensive overview of tools that may be suitable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers

Alternatively, Git supports HTTP, too, and so does BitBucket, as far as I know. Hence, it might be worth trying the URL with `https://` instead. Example: https://*youruser*@bitbucket.org/*youruser*/*yourrepository*.git

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue and landed up here. In my case one of my local gitlab project was throwing below error for push/pull. Other gitlab projects under same group were working fine.

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
```

Fix :

In file `<PROJECT_FOLDER>/.git/config` url was like  `url = ssh://git@gitlab.com`

Removing `ssh://` from url worked for me.